# Java Iterators - Trying to get a for each loop to work

Tags: java, iterator, foreach

So I have a `Tree<E>` class where `E` is the datatype held and organized by the tree. I'd like to iterate through the Tree like this, or in a way similar to this:

```
1.  Tree<String> tree=new Tree<String>();
2.  ...add some nodes...
3.  for (String s : tree)
4.      System.out.println(s);
```

It gives me an error on line 3 though.

```
Incompatible types
    required: java.lang.String
    found:    java.lang.Object
```

The following however works fine and as expected, performing a proper in-order traversal of the tree and printing each node out as it should:

```
for (TreeIterator<String> i = tree.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
    System.out.println(i.next());
```

My Tree class looks like this:

```
public class Tree<E> implements java.lang.Iterable{
    ...
    public TreeIterator<E> iterator(){
        return new TreeIterator<E>(root);//return an iterator for the root node
    }
    ....
}
```

And my TreeIterator class looks like this:

```
public class TreeIterator<E> implements java.util.Iterator<E>{
    public E next(){
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

But I want to get the `for (String s : tree)` loop working properly - any ideas? The whole point of this was to set up a clean foreach loop for use in my program, not to use that ugly for loop.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

---

**Edit**:

As per the [best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534020/java-iterators-trying-to-get-a-for-each-loop-to-work/2534036#2534036) (and [another equally good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534020/java-iterators-trying-to-get-a-for-each-loop-to-work/2534030#2534030) which was posted shortly after), the following made it work:

Changing

```
public class Tree<E> implements java.lang.Iterable{
    ....
}
```

to

```
public class Tree<E> implements java.lang.Iterable<E>{
    ....
}
```

...Thanks guys!

Comment: Your error is that your iterator is return an `Object` instead of a `String`.

Comment: Note: I've added some additional code.

Also, @Jordan: By my iterator do you mean the next() function? Right now, when I try to change next() from returning an E to returning an Object, it gives me an error and says to change it back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The foreach loop should be working fine if your `Tree<E>` class also implements the [`Iterable<E>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface. You need to make sure that your Iterator also returns the generic type `E`.

Comment: Oh - right! That makes sense, that's why it's asking for an `Object`; since right now my `Tree<E>` class is basically implementing `Iterable<Object>`!

Answer (score 4):

Your `Tree` has to implement `Iterable<E>` if you want it to work with the for each loop in a generic way (and hence your `iterator()` method must return `Iterator<E>`)

Answer (score 0):

The for loop in the code you pasted :

**3.  for (String s : tree)**

is wrongly typecasting elements of tree dataStructure to a collection (or array) of strings.

I suspect it should look something like:

```
for (String s : tree.getNodes()){...}
```

Where getNodes returns a collection of Strings.

Couldn't say though for sure, until you paste more of the code.

Comment: No the iterator returns just one String (or whatever E happens to be) each time next() is called. Thanks though!